# Plane layer thermal relief rotation with Altium?

Tags: pcb, altium, routing

It is straightforward to configure horizontal/vertical thermal relief connections with polygons, but with Plane layers, it seems the option isn't available. The result is not very professional (see the picture of GND pads).

Is it possible to rotate the thermal reliefs connections on plane layers?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my knowledge the answer is no. Not in the latest version of Altium, at least...

If I really need to be specific about my power plane connect style, I usually bite the bullet and define my "plane" layer as a signal layer and use a polygon to fill the entire layer, so I can use the design rules to control the connect style.